# StableDiffusion Colab - How to "make sure you're logged in with `huggingface-cli login`?"

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-datasets, huggingface

I'm trying to run the Colab example of the Huggingface StableDiffusion generative text-to-image model:

https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion
https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/diffusers/stable_diffusion.ipynb#scrollTo=xSKWBKFPArKS

However it gets stuck on the loading of the model:

[image]

Using the model requires registration at Huggingface and a token - I have one, I also got a token, which was accepted in the previous cell:

[image]

After the error I also executed the suggested command:
`!git config --global credential.helper store`

Although I don't think it's what has to be done.

I found this:
https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/repositories-getting-started
(Although I won't be pushing, but only downloading.)

> To be able to push your code to the Hub, you’ll need to
> authenticate somehow. The easiest way to do this is by installing the
> huggingface_hub CLI and running the login command:

```
python -m pip install huggingface_hub
huggingface-cli login
```

I installed it and run it:

```
!python -m pip install huggingface_hub
!huggingface-cli login
```

[image]

I logged in with my token (Read) - login successful.

However it still returns the same error on the attempt to download the model.

How to "make sure I'm logged in with `huggingface-cli login`"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found a solution on HackerNews in https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=32555028

Quoting PunkSpider (stop by the thread and give them an upvote):

> > > The solution seems to be to visit https://huggingface.co/CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4 and check a checkbox and click the button to confirm access.

Comment: which checkbox? couldn't find any